# Email meeting invite to a conatct

Tags: email, event

I want to send a email for meeting invite from salesforce to a non salesforce user when an event is created, the invite should get added to calendar of the recipient. Do we have any standard feature to get this done, or we need to apex code to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly not. You could use of course processes to automate this task.

For example look here:
https://automationchampion.com/tag/process-builder-to-send-email-alert-for-task/